# Get the current /delta cursor directly

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I would like to retrieve the delta cursor for the current state directly without making X requests to the server and back until has more is false.

Is this possible?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't currently possible. The /delta endpoint will initially return all entries necessary to inform you of the entire current state, so you'll need to call through all the pages first.

Comment: Are you planning implement this? As time goes pages will increase and its not all that fun to make requests on a mobile device. Also the responses are pretty heavy if you are not using them. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, don't know if or when.